# Plant ID - Stalky Plant with thin-leafed crown

Tags: identification, houseplants

The plant in this image is approximately 24 inches tall. It has a thin stem that naturally loses its leaves as the plant grows so that the growth remains only at the top. The leaves are long and thin with smooth ridges (see photos). My sister has an identical plant that usually yields purplish flowers in the spring, although the one in the photo hasn't blossomed yet after two years of growth. Any help identifying it would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo2]

Comment: What part of the world is this growing in?

Comment: Hi Kevin. This plant lives in West Texas.